# Push notification codelab Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in curl request

Tags: javascript, curl, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, chrome-gcm

I am following this tutorial https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/#send_a_request_from_the_command_line_for_fcm_to_push_a_message

And when I do this

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=AIzaSyCQHb2t8c3N255bH_CVmGych5QcNntFxYg" --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"APA91bE4RJ7_9m2eJ_zlg1F90bLjVX8ctVpCBN24ElAXF--4wS_nnxg4LzkbJWeTe-peMN_StmOaQTEoGeCCNZE5Mssux3T-KbfGRVmRWzeQZM8opfUyv7FVjI9iEfETHG3O7i1qkIb-\"]}"
```

I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

But I did everything as in the tutorial. And I put my api key there, my sender id is in the manifest.json as well, and  I put the subscription endpoint url there as well. This is the endpoint `endpoint: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/cl72SS1zE50:APA91bE4RJ7_9m2eJ_zlg1F…peMN_StmOaQTEoGeCCNZE5Mssux3T-KbfGRVmRWzeQZM8opfUyv7FVjI9iEfETHG3O7i1qkIb-`

So why do I get this error, what identifier does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl --header etc etc` is a shell command. The tutorial you link to says *From your terminal, run the cURL command below*

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier* is a JavaScript error message. You appear to be trying to enter that code in a JavaScript program (possibly by pasting it into a browser's Developer Tools Console or a Node.JS REPL).

You need to run the command on a shell (such as Bash or Windows Power Shell) not in a JS program.

Comment: I'm getting the same error but only on one specific link. Very odd. (Via shell)